# Bootstrap navbar not being active

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this in body tag:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
```

and the navbar:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a href="{{url('/home')}}">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="{{url('/login')}}">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
      </div>
 </nav>
```

Even if i clik on Login, Login navbar is not being active. It is only being active if i add `<li class="active">` but then even if i click on home login navbar is active.

Comment: Please create a fiddle for this issue. or instead of using class you can try using "id"

Comment: I think you are missing some js code for active class

Comment: Are the home and the login part on the same page? Because that is what the scroll spy does. If these are different pages, there is no way for Bootstrap to know what page to set as active.

Answer (score 0):

You can add class **active** by the request

```
<li class="{{ Request::is('*home*'  ) ? 'active' : ''  }}">
  <a href="{{url('/home')}}">Home</a>
</li>
```